# write your own malloc

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am writing my own malloc() and i have already figured the following

```
struct myblock
{
    struct myblock *next;
    struct myblock *prev;
    int isFree;
    unsigned availablesize;
    char *buffer;
}
```

and space #define MEM_BUFFER (1024) which will be "my ram". 
and if i am not wrong then i would have

```
char *array[MEM_BUFFER];
```

to have array of 1024 bytes (kindly correct me if i am wrong).

As we know that MEM_BUFFER will also contain the matadata of occupied space. I am bit confused that how should i start.

This is my main question.
should i assign the struct to the array on each allocation request (if yes then from struct char array ?) .

should i handle double linked list on heap and skip sizeof(myblock) bytes from the array.

I am thinking on this solution for last 2 days and I am still confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No,

```
char *array[MEM_BUFFER];
```

is not an array of 1024 bytes (unless `MEM_BUFFER` is set to `1024 / sizeof (char *)`) typically. It's an array of `MEM_BUFFER` character *pointers*.

You need just:

```
char array[MEM_BUFFER];
```

although a better name might be `heap_space`.

To make it consist of blocks, you'd need an additional pointer that is the first block:

```
struct myblock *heap = (struct myblock *) heap_space;
```

Then you can initialize that:

```
heap->next = NULL;
heap->prev = NULL;
heap->isFree = 1;
heap->availablesize = sizeof heap_space - sizeof *heap;
```

Not sure what `struct myblock.buffer` should do, I put the blocks *inside* the heap so the user memory for a block is at `(void *) (block + 1)`;

Comment: @unwind.. thanks you very much to giving me direction and i have started working. my second question is: struct myblock *heap = (struct myblock *) heap_space; this is how we can start by creating root node  by type casting heap_space, but what about the second node, I mean when the rquests will start coming then? how i will create the second node to start working. Same as we are creating first or .... how ?